# Why am I getting the CSRF token error when I skipped the action in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf

I have a Rails application where I'm using Vue (through webpacker) in some parts of the frontend.

From Vue I'm making a call to my server which needs to access the current_user (Devise), however, I'm getting the **Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.** error and the current user is not returned.

To avoid this I skipped the before_action like so:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :stripe_vue      

  def stripe_vue
     ...
  end
```

However, I'm still getting exactly the same issue.

It's kind of weird as I'm doing **exactly** the same thing in another controller and it works like charm.

Comment: What's the full error/message in the rails server?

Comment: use only this `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`  in `application_controller.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Comment this line

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

and final code should look like this

```
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Comment: That would impact the whole application thought. In order to do something "similar", I added the protect_from_forgery exception to stripe_vue before skipping verify_authenticity_token. Technically this should do the same, right?

The results at the end was the same, though :/